# What makes my array-like macro get contaminated

Tags: programming, tcolorbox

The following MWE is the simplified version of my project. `\CreateMacro` is used to create macros representing vocabularies. For example, `\CreateMacro{Newton}{$F=ma$}` creates `\Newton` with body `$F=ma$`. Invoking `\Newton` will print its body as well as insert `\Newton` into an array-like macro `\pushed`.

If we have created `\Einstein`, for example, and invoke `\Einstein`, then `\Einstein` will also be inserted into `\pushed`.

Invoking `\Render` will render all elements of `\pushed` and make `\pushed` empty.

However, I notice that sometimes `\pushed` gets contaminated as shown in the following output. I don't understand why `\Newton` still exists in the ninth item. In the ninth item  `\Newton` should not be there. It seems to be caused by a race condition. Could you figure out and fix it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}


\def\Format#1{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}%
        \textcolor{red}{#1}%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\newenvironment{Table}
{\begin{tcbraster}[%
        raster height=\textwidth,
        raster width=\linewidth,
        raster columns=2,
        raster rows=4,
        boxrule=2pt,
        raster column skip=-2pt,
        raster row skip=-2pt,
]}
{\end{tcbraster}}




\newcommand\CreateMacro[2]{%
    \expandafter\newrobustcmd\csname#1\endcsname{#2\gappto\pushed{\Format{#2}}}%
}


\gdef\Render{%
    \Table
        \pushed
    \endTable
    \gdef\pushed{}%
}




\begin{document}
\CreateMacro{Newton}{$F=ma$.}

\chapter{\Newton}
\Render


\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \CreateMacro{Einstein}{$E=mc^2$}
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you say what the intention of the code is, why the need for the regex replace? It makes it hard if you just post a lot of code and say it does the wrong thing without saying what the right thing is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\Newton` macro is passed to the `\leftmark`, because it appears in the chapter title, so it's evaluated when printing the heading and does a push.

You have to neutralize this behavior. A similar neutralization is needed if you plan to do the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{%
    % don't push as result of evaluating the heading
    \let\noexpand\push\noexpand\@gobble
    % the standard definition follows
    \MakeUppercase{%
      \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
          \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
        \fi
      \fi
      #1%
    }%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother


\newcommand\Format[1]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}%
        \textcolor{red}{#1}%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\newenvironment{Table}
{\begin{tcbraster}[%
        raster height=\textwidth,
        raster width=\linewidth,
        raster columns=2,
        raster rows=4,
        boxrule=2pt,
        raster column skip=-2pt,
        raster row skip=-2pt,
]}
{\end{tcbraster}}

\newcommand\CreateMacro[2]{%
  \expandafter\newrobustcmd\csname#1\endcsname{#2\push{\Format{#2}}}%
}

\newcommand\push[1]{\gappto\pushed{#1}}

\newcommand\Render{%
    \begin{Table}
        \pushed
    \end{Table}%
    \gdef\pushed{}%
}

\begin{document}
\CreateMacro{Newton}{$F=ma$.}
\CreateMacro{Einstein}{$E=mc^2$}

\chapter{\Newton}
\Render


\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A possibly more robust patch is to make `\push` equal to `\@gobble` when `\@starttoc` and `\@outputpage` are executed.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@starttoc}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\let\push\@gobble}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@outputpage}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\let\push\@gobble}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand\Format[1]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}%
        \textcolor{red}{#1}%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\newenvironment{Table}
{\begin{tcbraster}[%
        raster height=\textwidth,
        raster width=\linewidth,
        raster columns=2,
        raster rows=4,
        boxrule=2pt,
        raster column skip=-2pt,
        raster row skip=-2pt,
]}
{\end{tcbraster}}

\newcommand\CreateMacro[2]{%
  \expandafter\newrobustcmd\csname#1\endcsname{#2\push{\Format{#2}}}%
}

\newcommand\push[1]{\gappto\pushed{#1}}

\newcommand\Render{%
    \begin{Table}
        \pushed
    \end{Table}%
    \gdef\pushed{}%
}

\begin{document}
\CreateMacro{Newton}{$F=ma$.}
\CreateMacro{Einstein}{$E=mc^2$}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\Newton}
\Render


\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

However, the best way to proceed would be, in my opinion, avoiding such macros in titles altogether; in the code that follows, `\CreateMacro{Newton}{$F=ma$}` defines also `\Newton*` to be used in titles, which should be followed by `\pushNewton` at a safer time.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\newcommand\Format[1]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}%
        \textcolor{red}{#1}%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\newenvironment{Table}
{\begin{tcbraster}[%
        raster height=\textwidth,
        raster width=\linewidth,
        raster columns=2,
        raster rows=4,
        boxrule=2pt,
        raster column skip=-2pt,
        raster row skip=-2pt,
]}
{\end{tcbraster}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\CreateMacro[2]{%
  \expandafter\newrobustcmd\csname#1\endcsname{%
    \@ifstar{\@nameuse{#1star}}{\@nameuse{#1nostar}}%
  }%
  \@namedef{#1nostar}{#2\push{\Format{#2}}}%
  \@namedef{#1star}{#2}% \global\toggletrue{#1}}%
  \@namedef{push#1}{\push{\Format{#2}}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\push[1]{\gappto\pushed{#1}}

\newcommand\Render{%
    \begin{Table}
        \pushed
    \end{Table}%
    \gdef\pushed{}%
}

\begin{document}
\CreateMacro{Newton}{$F=ma$.}
\CreateMacro{Einstein}{$E=mc^2$}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\Newton*}\pushNewton
\Render


\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

    \item 
    \Einstein
    \Render

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please fix the table of contents issue as well?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian I made a couple of proposals; the best option, in my opinion, is the last one, because it's independent from packages used that could modify `\@starttoc` or `\@outputpage`.